# MutationObserver not detecting changes on a certain site

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

There's a certain site (getting to its subpage requires you to log in, therefore no link pasted) on which MutationObserver doesn't work, not at all.

This is the code:

```
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

const callback = (list, obs) => {
    for (const mut of list) console.log(mut);
};

const obs = new MutationObserver(callback);
obs.observe(document.body, config);
```

I know iFrames mess up MutationObservers, and it seems there's six of them total. Nevertheless, I'm observing the body element, and the iFrames are located very deeply into the DOM, therefore there's a lot of changes happening that should be observed anyway.

What could be the reason why MutationObservers aren't working? What are some of the popular ones?

Please, feel free to ask any questions that might help troubleshoot.

Comment: A `MutationObserver` callback will be triggered when `<iframe>` elements are added/removed but not when those `<iframe>`s' content is changed.

Comment: That's correct. There's a lot of elements that do not seem to be in any of the six iframes however, and they mutate a lot. Nevertheless, the CB is not called at all.

Comment: That is because you cannot access an `<iframe>`'s content from the main context if that `<iframe>`'s domain is different.

Comment: And if the iframes are same-origin you'll be able to observe them by specifying iframe.contentDocument.body as a target in observe().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MutationObserver works just fine.

Somebody substituted an empty function for console.log, hence all the confusion.